# Swift UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Greeting folks,
I'm trying to add UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell Programmatically , however the collectionView is not called ever. I went through the code several times with no luck. I looked around to find out also with no luck. I went through Youtube tutorials I found them do the same.

would you help please ☹️

```
    class adsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var adsImages: [UIImage]? {
        didSet{
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    let cellID = "Celled"

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return cv
    }()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(imageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)

        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false
        
        self.addSubview(collectionView)

    }
    
   

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}


extension adsTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! imageCell
        if let imageName = adsImages?[indexPath.item]{
            cell.imageView.image = imageName
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 300, height: frame.height - 10)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
      
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 14, bottom: 0, right: 14)
    }
    
    
    private class imageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let imageView: UIImageView = {
            let iv = UIImageView()
            iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            
            iv.clipsToBounds = true
            iv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            return iv
        }()
    
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setup()
        }
        
        func setup(){
            addSubview(imageView)
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
          
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the UITableView, cellForRowAt

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addViewCell", for: indexPath) as! adsTableViewCell
        cell.adsImages = images
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemTeal
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        return cell
        
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint. Is `awakeFromNib` called?  Have you tried adding the collection view (and setting the constraints) to the cell's `contentView`?

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your response. No it is not called (awakeFromNib). Also YES I tried to add it to contentView but still same

Comment: If your tableview cell is not linked to a nib or storyboard, `awakeFromNib` is not called. You should override [`init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623276-init)

Comment: @Paulw11 I found the solution thank you

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution
simply I had to change :

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
```

To

```
override required init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
       super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
       setup()
   }
```

and it is work fine now